# Spring HTTP interface ndjson support

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring HTTP interface with `application/x-ndjson` Content-type is not creating a new line delimited JSON in the request body.

```
    @PostExchange(contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestBody Map<String, String>... data);
```

The request body is generated as

```
[{\"1\":\"name\",\"2\":\"name\"}]
```

Mockserver request log

```
  {
    "method" : "POST",
    "path" : "/",
    "headers" : {
      "user-agent" : [ "ReactorNetty/1.1.10" ],
      "host" : [ "localhost:8787" ],
      "content-length" : [ "25" ],
      "accept-encoding" : [ "gzip" ],
      "accept" : [ "*/*" ],
      "Content-Type" : [ "application/x-ndjson" ]
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : false,
    "protocol" : "HTTP_1_1",
    "localAddress" : "127.0.0.1:8787",
    "remoteAddress" : "127.0.0.1:50897",
    "body" : "[{\"1\":\"name\",\"2\":\"name\"}]"
  }
```

Example project - https://github.com/shinusuresh/httpinterface-ndjson

Any help is appreciated.